# CSS not inside tag

Tags: html, css

I have such html:

```
   <div class="entry">
     <p></p> //text-indent here
     <blockquote>
      <p></p> //no text-indent here
     </blockquote>
    </div>
```

I want to ident only `<p>` tag inside `.entry` but not `<p>` inside `.entry blockquote`

My CSS

```
.entry{
  p{
    margin: .85em auto;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-indent: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

Is there any way just to modify existing css may be jusing `not` selector somehow without introducing any new rules?

Comment: you might just be able to use a non breaking space; (`&nbsp`) in front of the one you want to indent

Comment: I don't think `class=".entry"` is going to work well. Anyway, why don't you want to introduce new rules?

Comment: @torazaburo there is two reasons first that is legacy css so I do not want to change that a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352952/optimize-css-with-stylus

Comment: The `.` doesn't belong in the class-call in the HTML. Only in the CSS.

Comment: Also, why do you have a `<p>` inside a `<blockquote>` - if anything, it should be the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are two ways to do that:

**1. Use the child selector (`>`) to style only the top level paragraph:**

```css
/* All paragraphs inherit these styles */
.entry p {
    margin: .85em auto;
    line-height: 1.7;
}
/* Only the top level paragraphs get text indent */
.entry > p {
    text-indent: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
    <p>Outer paragraph section</p> 
    <blockquote>
        <p>Inner paragraph section</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

**2. Use the descendant selector to style all paragraphs and then override the inner paragraph style:**

```css
/* All paragraphs inherit these styles */
.entry p {
    margin: .85em auto;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-indent: 1.5em;
}
/* Override/Reset the text-indent property of inner paragraphs */
.entry blockquote p {
    text-indent:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
    <p>Outer paragraph</p> 
    <blockquote>
        <p>Inner paragraph</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Would use of `stylis` would help to do that with the less css lines in particular case?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Sorry I didn't realize you are using less. I don't really have experience with less so I don't know about `stylis`. The css I entered above should work as plain css.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be more specific with the elements you don't want indented. See my CSS below. Also, the CSS you posted would be valid SCSS but not normal CSS, just fyi.

```
  .entry blockquote p {
      text-indent: 0;
  }
```